# Method not found when calling Seleno

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver, seleno

I'm new to automation testing. I'm trying to use Seleno for my project:
Seleno:

```
public static class BrowserHost
{
    public static readonly SelenoHost Instance = new SelenoHost();
    public static readonly string RootUrl = @"link to web";

    static BrowserHost()
    {
        Instance.Run("projectname", 80, w => w.WithRemoteWebDriver(() => new ChromeDriver()));

    }
}
```

Calling Seleno in test method:

```
private IWebDriver driver = BrowserHost.Instance.Application.Browser;
```

But Application returns null and respectively Browser throws System.NullReferenceException. The whole error is :

> OneTimeSetUp: System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'project name' threw an exception.
>     ----> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException : An exception was thrown while executing a resolve operation. See the InnerException for details. ---> Method not found: 'OpenQA.Selenium.ITimeouts OpenQA.Selenium.ITimeouts.ImplicitlyWait(System.TimeSpan)'. (See inner exception for details.)
>     ----> System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'OpenQA.Selenium.ITimeouts OpenQA.Selenium.ITimeouts.ImplicitlyWait(System.TimeSpan)'.

Could you please help me to find where I might mistake